# Plot Figure in Web Browser (Offline) in Python Using Flask, accessing .js and .css Files on my local drive

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, plotly

I need some pointing in the right direction. I have a python flask script that opens up a form on my web browser at http://localhost:8000. When I enter a number into the field and press submit, it renders a dummy figure. It works works great when I'm connected to the internet but when I'm on a server that restricts internet access, it wont render the figure.

There are 3 files/links it accesses from within the HTML files:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js

How can I get these files onto my local and have the HTML files access them? I am new to HTML and the javascript world.

Here is my app.py, and two template HTML files.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import json

import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio

pio.renderers.default = 'browser' # or 'colab' or 'iframe' or 'iframe_connected' or 'sphinx_gallery'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b"my_secret_key"

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'auto_number' in request.form:
        graphJSON = gm()
        return render_template('plot_fig.html', graphJSON=graphJSON) 
    return render_template("home.html")

def gm():
    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[0,1,2,1,0], mode='markers'))
    fig.update_layout(title="Test Figure")
    fig.update_traces(marker={'size': 15})
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
    return graphJSON
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=False)
```

home.html

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="text-center py-5">Figure Generator</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form class="pure-form" method="POST">

                    <label for="LocoNum" class="form-label">Enter any number here:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="auto_number" placeholder="1234" class="form-control">
                    <p></p>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

plot_fig.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='chart' class='chart'></div>
</body>

<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var graphs = {{graphJSON | safe}};
  Plotly.plot('chart',graphs,{});
</script>

</html>
```